# Map "defaultValue" and "source" of a react-admin text input to two different properties of the same object

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a weird API endpoint where there are two properties for the same field.

```
{
 id:"123",
 title: {
  rendered: "Hi, i'm rendered",
  raw: "<p> Hi, I'm the title</p>"
}
```

in the Edit form, I have a  Component like so:

```
        <TextInput
            source="title.raw"
            defaultValue="title.rendered"
            validation={{ text: true }}
            validate={required()}
            />
```

But that's not working. How can I get the title.rendered to show up as default value but have title.raw be what's sent back to the endpoint/ server?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve ? 
Just passing to data as props to the <TextInput> ?

Comment: @SimonBruneaud I have the data I need via title.rendered. I just can't get it as the default value. When I use it as in my example, it renders literally as "title.rendered" on text input. I need it to interpoloate the value of title.rendered as the default on the input on load and when edited, POST to title.raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { FormDataConsumer } from 'react-admin'

<Edit ...>
  ...
  <FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) =>
      <TextInput
        source="title.raw"
        defaultValue={formData.title.rendered}
        validation={{ text: true }}
        validate={required()}
      />
    }
  </FormDataConsumer>
</Edit>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Where did you learn about this component? I see very little about it in the official docs.

Comment: Yes, there is not much information, but it is quite simple:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs